# CIDetector not detecting the face in ios7

Tags: ios, iphone, detection, ciimage

I want to detect the face and to crop the face out of it, but when i capture the image using imagePicker the face features array after detection gives an empty array. But when i used to give a sample image (jpg) the face has been detected.

my code to detect the face features

```
-(void)findFace:(UIImage*)image
{
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh forKey: CIDetectorAccuracy];
    CIDetector  *detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType: CIDetectorTypeFace context: nil options: options];

    CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage: [image CGImage]];

    NSNumber *orientation = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[image imageOrientation]+1];
    NSDictionary *fOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:orientation forKey: CIDetectorImageOrientation];
//    NSArray *features = [detector featuresInImage:ciImage options:fOptions];
    NSArray* features = [detector featuresInImage:ciImage];
    for (CIFaceFeature *f in features) {

        NSLog(@"left eye found: %@", (f. hasLeftEyePosition ? @"YES" : @"NO"));

        NSLog(@"right eye found: %@", (f. hasRightEyePosition ? @"YES" : @"NO"));

        NSLog(@"mouth found: %@", (f. hasMouthPosition ? @"YES" : @"NO"));

        if(f.hasLeftEyePosition)

            NSLog(@"left eye position x = %f , y = %f", f.leftEyePosition.x, f.leftEyePosition.y);

        if(f.hasRightEyePosition)

            NSLog(@"right eye position x = %f , y = %f", f.rightEyePosition.x, f.rightEyePosition.y);

        if(f.hasMouthPosition)

            NSLog(@"mouth position x = %f , y = %f", f.mouthPosition.x, f.mouthPosition.y);

    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Was the face image captured from the cam clear enough?

Comment: ofcourse, its clear and the detector accuracy is also give high. Is that we want to give only a JPG image for detection?

Comment: No, PNG is not an issue. Try displaying the image that you pass to the  findface method, just to verify if its as expected.

Comment: I am just following the tutorials and sample codes. i set the frameworks also in build phases, included the header in that respective controllers. For sample images its detecting the face but for the imagePicker images only its not detecting.

Comment: I have posted the image, that i am trying to detect face.

Comment: Guys, Its the problem of image orientation. when i tried to give an image orientation to the captured image it works fine, but some times its not detecting the face and gives the empty image.